# Websphere 8.5 java.lang.NumberFormatException: WSWS3435E: Error: Invalid date/time. Received an empty string for a date/time value

Tags: java, web-services, xsd

I have issue with the data format when sending SOAP request to Websphere 8.5

I had tried with different data formats when sending through soapUI. None of them worked.

WSDL definition of the element `<element name="submittedTimeStamp" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>`

SOAPUI request `<submittedTimeStamp>06142011</submittedTimeStamp>`

Here is the complete error Log from the server log:

```
[8/26/19 10:26:09:897 EDT] 000000b0 WebServicesSe E com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServlet doPost WSWS3227E:  Error: Exception:
                                 WebServicesFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException
 faultString: java.lang.NumberFormatException: WSWS3435E: Error: Invalid date/time.  Received an empty string for a date/time value. Message being parsed: 
 faultActor: null
 faultDetail: 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: WSWS3435E: Error: Invalid date/time.  Received an empty string for a date/time value. Message being parsed: 
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesFault.makeFault(WebServicesFault.java:300)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart._getSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:1090)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.SOAPPart.getEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:656)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandlerChain.handleRequest(JAXRPCHandlerChain.java:308)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandler.invokeServerRequestHandler(JAXRPCHandler.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandler$1.invoke(JAXRPCHandler.java:381)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:226)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesEngine.invoke(WebServicesEngine.java:336)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServlet.doPost(WebServicesServlet.java:1239)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServletBase.service(WebServicesServletBase.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

Answer (score 0):

The lexical value of `xsd:dateTime` follows the format `[-]CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]`, so the following values are valid:

- 2019-08-27T21:32:52
- 2019-08-27T21:32:52+02:00
- 2019-08-27T21:32:52Z

But, the following are invalid:

- 2019-08-27 (all parts must be specified)
- 2019-08-27T21:32 (all parts must be specified)
- 06142011 (invalid format)

Comment: Thanks. `2019-08-26T18:41:26.818Z` did worked for me.